# Best way to download many images into Azure App Service .Net Core app for processing

Tags: azure, azure-blob-storage, azure-web-app-service

I have over 500 large image files that I need to process in my .NET Core app hosted in an Azure App Service. That said, I need to download all of the images and run them through a machine learning categorization function in my code. I currently use blob storage as my mechanism for storing the images, but downloading all those images via blob rest api is slow. Is there a better architecture in Azure that I should be making use of to greatly increase performance of processing these images? Perhaps a storage mechanism much faster than blob storage?

Comment: The blob storage should be the best choice, as well for downloading blobs, you can take a look at [Azure Storage Data Movement Library](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net-data-movement#microsoft-azure-storage-data-movement-library-0120).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I tried at my side. Even the Storage Account is at the same location as my web app, it will take about 3-6 second to download a 30MB file. (In VM, it will only take less than 1 second)

My suggestions:

1. You can zip your pictures into one archive file, and download it. It would be faster than downloading them one by one.
2. You can use [DownloadToFileParallelAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.cloudblob.downloadtofileparallelasync?view=azure-dotnet) method to download a file. It would be a little faster.
3. You can refer to the official tutorial to [Download large amounts of random data from Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-scalable-app-download-files)